# Crystal reports 10 selection between time

Tags: crystal-reports

Being new to Crystal could someone point me in the correct direction.

I have a field,  in an SQL view which is datetime.
I have converted this to time only using

```
time ({rep_Sterling_YEARLYSHEETCOUNT.StartDateAndTime})
```

I now want to use this in a further formula to determine if the operation occurred on the day or the night shift

```
if {@Time Convert} > #06:00:00# and {@Time Convert} < #18:00:00#
Then 'Days'
Else 'Nights'
```

However I am told 'A Date-time is required here.

What have I got wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enclose in betweed `#` it will be treated as datetime and hence the error.

So change like this:

```
if {@Time Convert} > Ctime("06:00:00") and
 {@Time Convert} < Ctime("18:00:00")
Then 'Days'
Else 'Nights'
```

Comment: Looks Good. Thank you very much

Comment: If it worked..then accept it as answered so that others can use it